# Dropdown не работает в IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Dropdown работает везде, кроме IE11. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
var dropdownBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown__btn");

for (var i = 0; i < dropdownBtns.length; i++) {
  dropdownBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    showDropdown(this.closest(".dropdown"));
  });
}

function showDropdown(dropdown) {
  var content = dropdown.querySelector(".dropdown__content");
  var btn = dropdown.querySelector(".dropdown__btn");
  btn.classList.toggle("dropdown__btn--active");
  content.classList.toggle("dropdown__content--active");
}
```

Полный пример: [тут](https://codepen.io/natasha-kalachewa/pen/BayaNyY)

Comment: Вы знаете, что codepen не рабоатет в IE11? Приведите полный код здесь, в вопросе.

Comment: Во время разработки смотрите консоль в devTools. Там пишутся важные сообщения и ошибки. Например, у вас не работает, потому что IE11 не поддерживает метод `closest`.

Comment: да, так и есть, спасибо!

Comment: document.querySelectorAll в IE11 нужно насильно объявлять массивом. Могут быть проблемы, если в последующем будут использоваться соответствующие методы перебора массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest` отсутствует в IE11:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest - "Browser compatibility"

Используйте Polyfill.